# Possible bug: What is the meaning of this Rascal grammar-rule?

Tags: context-free-grammar, rascal

SO I'm working on rewriting grammars to other forms of the same grammar and am using the function grammar2rascal(g), however it produces a (in my opinion) weird result when trying to write back follow/precede restrictions. I was wondering if someone could explain to me what this means and why rascal works like this. I'm assuming rascal internally rewrites some things and therefore comes up with this, however I'd still like to understand its meaning and use.

So here goes:

```
lexical Id = "a" !<< [a-z]+ !>> "b";
```

becomes:

```
lex("Id"){prod(lex("Id"),[conditional(iter(\char-class([range(97,122)])),{\not-follow(lit("b")),\not-precede(lit("a"))})],{})}
```

which seems fine, but is written back as:

```
lexical Id = [a-z]+ !>> "b" !<< [a-z]+ !>> "b";
```

This completely removes the not preceded by "a" part of the rule. So am I missing something or is this some sort of bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code of the `grammar2rascal` there is a bug where the `precede` is handled incorrectly. This is fixed in [1c7fed](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/commit/1c7fedd0ee81c2651947b8344077f2dbf44486c2), this should appear on the unstable update site in around an hour (16:00 CET).

And indeed, now it prints, as you would expect:

```
lexical Id = "a" !<< [a-z]+ !>> "b";
```

Comment: Luckily I'm on the unstable version. I'll wait for that update then :) Thank you for clearing this up!